# c# picturebox in toolstrippanel

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

Does anyone have idea how to add picturebox to toolstripcontainer.toptoolstrippanel? I got warning message: 
     Warning: Controls added to this collection must be of type 'ToolStrip'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message indicates you can add only a `ToolStrip` instances to the `TopToolStripPanel`. On the other hand you could add the PictureBox image to the [Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.items.aspx) property of a `ToolStrip`:

```
var pb = new PictureBox();
pb.Load(@"c:\work\foo.png");
var ts = new ToolStrip();
ts.Items.Add(pb.Image);
toolStripContainer1.TopToolStripPanel.Controls.Add(ts);
```

Comment: Does this mean some code in the application can alter the image as well? or it is fixed?

Comment: @Sean87, no, it is not fixed, you could always manipulate the Items property and add remove elements to it.